# Difference between two cards. Radeon and Gigabyte

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi, amd-radeon

I am looking to buy I decent Radeon card that will support at least 4 HD monitors (1920*1080).

I stumbled upon these two listings on Amazon.

[VisionTek](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006V6RHVM) vs. [Gigabyte](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00752QYLK)

Can they both support 4 HD displays, are there any differences other then the price and branding?

Comment: Have you looked at the manufacture specifications for these products?

Comment: How did you know the first one supports 4 monitors, I can't find this in the spec sheet.

Comment: Since the card supports Display Port's multi-stream, assuming you have monitors that have DisplayPort in and DisplayPort out, you should be able to leverage the Eyefinity to get up to 6 displays . . . not sure where @Ramhound got specs to say otherwise?

Comment: @ernie - I am going off by the fact the first product specifically indicates support for 4 displays and the other seems to point to only 3 monitors.  I should have looked at the base specifications for the 7970 I suppose

Comment: @Ramhound I'm still curious where you got the 3 number?  Looking at the Gigabyte page for the card, it specifically states "Multi-view 4" on the specifications tab?  I'm not trying to nit-pick, just hoping our discussion might help others in the future to know what particular specification is worth looking at for determining how many displays a card can support . . . I'm considering video ports, Eyefinity, and multi-view.  What spec did you look at?

Comment: @ernie - `Multi-view 4` does not exist on the Amazon page I looked at. Furthermore the `Amazon Question` that answers this question wasn't displayed on my phone because it didn't exist yet. I did not look up the Gigabyte specifications, I only used the supplied links, since that was the data provided. Lets just agree I skipped a vital step in my thought process, the author should have done better research, and this isn't a very good question.  The other product page had this "AMD Eyefinity multi-display technology. Support up to 4 Displays"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be differences, but ultimately the only thing vendors do is to follow the schematics AMD provides; they have little choice in the design of the board.

If the specs are all the same, most likely the graphics boards are the same, with exception of the quality of components used and/or the colling system.

For reference, here are the links to the manufacturer's product pages:

- [VisionTek](http://www.visiontek.com/7000-series/hd-7970.html)
- [Gigabyte](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4102#sp)

Funny thing about VisionTek is that they don't divulge the board's specs.

Comment: Would you know where it says how many monitors Gigabyte supports.
I am really unfamiliar with video cards.

Comment: I am also unfamiliar with modern graphics cards, but I would go by the ports they have. Since they both have the same number of ports (i.e. 1 DVI, 1 HDMI and 2 DisplayPort), they should both support 4 displays, which is why I am also waiting on @Ramhound answer.

Comment: I believe your thinking makes sense. I often read that graphic cards with eyefinity can support up to 6 monitors.

Comment: Got my answer! It is possible to run up to 6 displays with this card.
http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/extremewindows/archive/2013/01/07/amd-radeon-7970-with-eyefinity-display-groups-and-directx-11.aspx 
(mentioned at the end of the blog posting)